# Laravel - Check to see if collection has relation

Tags: php, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a form with some checkboxes and when certain checkboxes are checked, I conditionally create a join to an Eloquent model

```
$collection = Model::with('some_relation')
     ->when(!is_null($request->input('make')), function($query) {
         $query->with('make');
      })
      ->get();
```

This all works as expected.

What I need to be able to do is check for the existence of that relation in a view. In my view I have a table and need to know if the relation exists and if it does I create a table header for that relation.

I have tried everything I can find and nothing works. I've even tried the following but it returns true even if the relation doesn't exist

```
$test = $collection->contains(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value['make'];
});
```

I've also tried `count($collection->make);` but it says

> Property [make] does not exist on this collection instance

All I want it to see if the relationship exists

Comment: Do you want to check every item or only the first one?

Comment: Every time. The first for the table header and the other for the TD

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
$test = $collection->filter->relationLoaded('make')->isEmpty();
```

Will return true if the relation doesn't exist